# NSArray of Buttons that use Object Data

Tags: ios

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, so I'll first explain what I'm trying to do.

I am generating buttons using data from an array of Annotation objects.

I then want the user to be able to click on a button, have a textfield appear, and whatever they type will overwrite the text in the relevant Annotation object and also button.

So I have the buttons being generated by the Annotation data, but this is where I get stuck.

```
//Make a button for each Annotion if x value within 0 - 1400 boundary.
    for(Annotation * ack in markerPoints)
    {
        if ([ack x] > 0 && [ack x] < 1401)
        {
            UIButton * marker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            [marker addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(markerPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            marker.frame=CGRectMake([ack x],[ack y],100,50);
            [marker setTitle:[ack textData] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

            [marker setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [marker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [self addSubview:marker ];
            [markerButtonList addObject:marker];

        }
    }
```

When the user presses the button, how can I tell which Annotation object it is related to so I can change the Annotation textData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the tag of each button with the array index value and fetch the tag in the method when its get called.
Example:

> ```
> //Make a button for each Annotion if x value within 0 - 1400 boundary.
> NSInteger index = 0;
> for(Annotation * ack in markerPoints)
> {
>     if ([ack x] > 0 && [ack x] < 1401)
>     {
>         UIButton * marker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
>         [marker addTarget:self
>                    action:@selector(markerPressed:)
>          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
>         marker.frame=CGRectMake([ack x],[ack y],100,50);
>         [marker setTitle:[ack textData] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
>         [marker setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [marker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
>         [market setTag:index];
>         [self addSubview:marker ];
>         [markerButtonList addObject:marker];    
>     }
>     index++;
> }
>
> -(void)markerPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
>     Annotation * ack_selected = [markerPoints objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
> }
> ```

Comment: But it is an NSMutableArray, does it still have an index value?

I need to be able to delete the buttons too.

Comment: And make sure the tag value is != 0, so you won't have unexpected behaviur.

Comment: +1. Same answer, but you was a bit faster with the update than me ;)

Comment: @AnotherNewbie for sure a `NSMutableArray` object has an index, because its still an array, so a **sorted** list, just with the ability to be mutated dynamicly ;) what you think about is `NSSet`, an **unsorted** list ;)